# What is the mount on this Beston lens?

Tags: lens, canon, lens-mount, lens-adapter

Bought this lens cheap at an estate sale, but now I'm trying to figure out the adapter I need to get it to fit my Rebel XS body.
I've looked at dozens of pictures on the internet, but cannot narrow down what this mount is exactly.
[image: pic of connecting end of lens]

[image: pic of front end of lens]

per request here are a few additional shots to show the flanges. 1st additional pic with the aperture bar at the top (like the previous pix) and the second additional pic at a slight angle to show flange definition, and the third additional pic with the aperture bar at the bottom to show flanges that weren't quite viewable in 1st pic.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A straight-on picture of the back of the lens could be helpful... this is not showing the flanges very well.

Comment: Thanks, I added 3 pics. Hope this show them clearly enough.

Comment: Mystery? Beston is etched right on the front.

Comment: Every time I googled adapter Beston to Canon--nothing came up, I assumed it was a minor brand

Comment: Why do call it a breech mount? Does the lens stay in the same orientation with respect to the camera body when you mount it (like the Canon FD breech mount lenses), or do you just rotate the lens onto the camera body (like all modern bayonet mount SLR lenses do)?

Comment: K mount according to this forum  https://www.pentaxforums.com/userreviews/beston-mc-28mm-f2-8.html

Comment: That's a bayonet mount, not a breech mount. Pentax "K", to be specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be an early [Pentax "K" mount.](https://www.pentaxforums.com/articles/photo-articles/evolution-of-pentax-k-mount.html) The recessed Aperture Simulator slot opposite the Aperture control lever is the clue. This slot is clearly visible in your first photo.

[image]

There are lots of inexpensive adapters available to mount Pentax "K" mount lenses on your Canon EOS Rebel XS. This one costs about $15.

[Vello Pentax K Lens to Canon EF-S-Mount Camera Lens Adapter](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1349589-REG/vello_la_cef_pk_pentax_k_lens_mount.html)

[image]

Comment: Worth to mention that the aperture lever should be unmounted before using K/EF(-S) adapter. Otherwise it will cause damage of the mirror in camera.

Comment: Thank you, Mike, for the answer.

Comment: Thank you, Artur. How would I "unmount" the aperture lever?

Comment: Some lenses can interfere with the larger mirror of a full frame camera like a 5D or 6D. Since you are using an APS-C crop camera, the mirror is much smaller and won’t be a problem.

Comment: @joncow you'll have to partially disassemble the lens. Unfortunately, the exact steps are rather manufacturer specific. Alternatively ... you can just saw the lever up, but that makes the lens permanently unusable as an actual Pentax lens - and be careful where the metal dust will go.